# Mongoose: Schema validate not working without saving the document

Tags: validation, mongoose

Mongoose `Schema` validation not working when I tries to create embedded schema object, which won't be stored in separate collection. Below is my schema,

My Embedded Schema with the validator,

```
var myValidator = function(value) {
   return value.length > 10;
}

var myValidator2 = function(value) {
   return value.length < 5;
}

var subSchema = new Schema({
    "key1": {type: String, "default": null, validate: [myValidator, "Too short value"]},
    "key2": {type: String, validate: [myValidator2, "Too long"]}
});
```

And in my model file, I try like this,

```
var sub1 = new subSchema({key1: "short", "key2": "good"});
```

It should throw error, since the `key1`'s value is "**short**" which is invalid for the validator.

But it's throwing any error, it just accepts and the parent model stores it.

Answer (score 1):

[Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) performs validation on [save()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) or `modelInstance.validate()` only. If you need to validate without saving the document to database, you have these following options,

**1. Calling validate()**

Calling `validate()` on `subSchema` model object will throw error via `callback`

```
sub1.validate(function(error) {
    // but digging this error object is tedious process
});
```

**2. Calling validator itself**

```
if (myValidator(value)) {
   // do action
} else {
   // throw error
}
```

I recommend this solution, because you just need to call the validator directly. But keep in mind, unlike [Schema Validators](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html), you need to do manually call the validator before every [save()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save).